# How to bind List<> to listbox?

Tags: asp.net, listbox

.aspx:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbavailablefields" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

.cs:

```
Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
ListBox listbox = new ListBox();
listbox = (ListBox)page.FindControl("lbavailablefields");
listbox.DataSource = AllSelectedFieldList;
listbox.DataBind();
```

Where `AllSelectedFieldList` is `List<MyClass>`

```
class MyClass
{
    string Value;
    string Text; 
}
```

But when running above code gives an error as `object reference not set to an object`

**Edited**
As I'm accessing control in static method I have used `context` to find control.

Comment: what is `AllSelectedFieldList` here? where it is populated

Comment: @un-lucky, AllSelectedFieldList is list of Myclass..

Comment: Add this code and say you stil have error or not: `if(listbox != null) listbox.DataSource = AllSelectedFieldList; ...`

Comment: is that in the current context? and also make sure that `listbox ` is not null

Comment: both mark up and code belongs to same page?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: if then, op will come up with another question that nothing is displaying

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, still getting same error after check for null..!

Comment: Then why find control? you can't access it directly?

Comment: remove this `ListBox listbox = new ListBox();` and change this: `listbox = (ListBox)page.FindControl("lbassgnedfields");` to this: `var listbox = (ListBox)page.FindControl("lbassgnedfields");`, and keep the if, say the result

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, It returns null...!

Comment: You have mistyping, the `ID` of `ListBox` is `lbavailablefields`, but you try to find `lbassgnedfields`

Comment: @MehdiDehghani,Actually there are two listboxes and by mistake I post another listbox code but that is Ok I have checked that..

Comment: If you have removed `ListBox listbox = new ListBox();` and the `ID` is correct, and with that `if` you have not any error, so the problem is, the ListBox can not be found, so make sure the Page is found correctly, for example by log the `page.Title`

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, actually I'm not getting that control when I add same code on non-static function in code behind and check if listbox ID for null then that return me null value...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110622/discussion-between-kaishu-and-mehdi-dehghani).